# Send to other server like my own - Virtual Device

Tags: php, html

How do I change the user agent of my browser so the the site  I am viewing thinks I am viewing from a phone or tablet?

Currently sites see me as a PC (correctly) and I am I unable to test the mobile parts of the site.

Comment: User agent switcher for [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) and user agent switcher for [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg). These would be a good place to start.

Comment: Hmm - but is still not got right page from server - like mobil page - i have try them. Is work if you make web page like basic responsive - is css and JS crontrol - but still not same like mobil or table. I make a RESS - just Google like to say use RES and not SEO - cause is easyer for them to seek - but mobil page Work not great ( just same high data send )

Comment: You can try see this page [link](http://andmag.se/ress/) http://andmag.se/ress/ to see what y browse like :-)

Comment: If you want to see exactly what a mobile device would see then you'll have to use a service like browserstack. You can only control the useragent and size of the browser. The rendering engine will have its own quirks.